# FreeRTOS performance Tasks vs. Timers

Tags: freertos

I have several workloads that require frequent execution. There are two possibilities:

1. Creating a recurring FreeRTOS timer.
2. Creating a FreeRTOS task with a `vTaskDelay` in the loop.

From a performance standpoint… are both of these options equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use create a task using vTaskDelayUntil().
Which allows for absolute periods, i believe it is the most straightforward way of doing it.
So something like this,

```cpp
void myTask(void* param)
{
  // do some configuration stuff
  auto xLastWakeTime = xTaskGetTickCount();
  auto frequency_in_Hz = 1000;
  float adc_read{};
  //run the task
  for(;;)
  {        
    acd_read = read_adc();
    // go idle and give processor time to other tasks
    vTaskDelayUntil(&xLastWakeTime,configTICK_RATE_HZ/frequency_in_Hz);
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that by default the configTICK_RATE_HZ might not be 1000, play around with the value, if the value is less than 1000 then you won't be able to have frequencies > 1kHz.
Basically the configTICK_RATE_HZ determines how often the SysTick is updated,(how often the SysTick interrup is called) so higher values mean more time interrupting, but more control over the frequency you want to operate on.